# HTTP GET In Python

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I have a bash script that downloads a lot of files from a URL and saves them to my Computer like:

```
curl 'http://website.com/shop.php?store_id=[66-900]&page=[7-444]&PHPSESSID=phpsessid' -O
```

(and a bunch of headers set, the typical request you get when you copy a request as curl in firefox)

Tried to rewrite the script in python but turns out it is very hard (complete newbie)
like:

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'PHPSESSID': '<phpsessid here>',
}

headers = {
    '<bunch of header stuff here>'
}

params = (
    ('store_id', '[66-900]'),
    ('page', '[7-444]'),
    ('PHPSESSID', '<phpsessid here>'),
)

response = requests.get('http://website.com/shop.php', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)
```

But it just doesn't do anything (curl command downloading everything as commanded)
I realised I may need to write my downloaded stuff to a file but am completly lost since I am not handling one file but hundreds of files and as seen from the curl command above.

Completly lost what I am missing or need to do to replicate a curl request like that in python, ANY help appreciated!

Comment: `requests` may get something but it will not save it in file automatically. You should check what you have in `response.content` and write code which write it in file.

Comment: it seems you should write it as `for`-loop and use single value in `store_id` instead of `[66-900]` and the same with `page`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `for`-loops instead of `[66-900]`, `[7-444]`

```
for store_id in range(66, 990+1):
    for page in range(7, 444+1):

        params = {
           'store_id': store_id,
           'page': page,
           'PHPSESSID': '<phpsessid here>',
        }

        response = requests.get(...)

        with open(f"{store_id}-{page}", "wb") as fh:
             fh.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a range as you can do it when using curl.

As @furas noted, you can use a loop, because curl sends requests with all parameter combinations from the ranges.

Function `response.get` returns an object of class `requests.models.Response`, so you should use `json()` method or properties `content` (returns bytes) and `text` (returns string).